# Zend Framework 1 pass parameters using get to the route

Tags: php, zend-framework, http-post, http-get, zend-route

I hope the title does not sound too confusing, but I had no idea how to name my problem.

Brief intro:
I'm using Zend 1.1X.
At the moment I've been working with a search form sending few parameters via POST.

Now I have to change it to use GET, I have a route created looking similar to that:

```
"search/what/:what/shape/:shape"
```

and so on, I also have 2 optional parameters which takes null as default.

I'm trying to generate an URL (using Zend View Helper Url) at form's action, but it throws an exception:

```
Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Router_Exception' with message what is not specified
```

I Now don't have idea what should I do. If I change my route to "search" only, it then sends the form correctly, but I end up with `"search?what=XXXX&shape=YYYY"` instead of `"search/what/XXXX/shape/YYYY"`.

Is there any way that could be handled the way I like??? :>

@EDIT

I think this should also be mentioned - I have a different form, similar one, pointing to a route without parameters specified as well and the uri gets "translated" to the form of "key/value" pairs. The only difference between them is that the first one does not use Url helper, instead has the method part hard-coded and my form is being submitted programatically (button => jQuery stuff => submit). Would that make a difference here, as I believe it should not? :>

I hope any possible source of this behaviour will come up to you, because I'm really stuck at the moment and I simply can't find what's wrong..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you use Zend View Helper Url?

Comment: echo $this->url(array(),  'search', true); - the route name is search as well ;>

Answer (score 0):

With the `GET` method a form generates an url like this: `action?param1=val1&param2=val2&....`
I see two solutions:
The first is to regenerate the URL by javacsript, we can imagine something like this:

```
<form method="get" id="id_form">
....
</form>
<script> 
    var objet_form = document.getElementById('id_form');

    function gestionclic(event){
        var url = objet_form.action;
        for(var i = 0; i < objet_form.length; i++){
            url += "/" + objet_form[i].name + "/" + objet_form[i].value;
        }
        objet_form.action = url;
    }

    if (objet_form.addEventListener){
        objet_form.addEventListener("submit", gestionclic, false);
    } else{
        objet_form.attachEvent("onsubmit", gestionclic, false);
    }
</script>
```

But I don't think this is a good solution.

The second is to manage it with a plugin:

For the plugin, it must be declared in the `bootstrap`. 
For example:

```
public function _initPlugins(){
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $front->registerPlugin(new Application_Plugin_PRoutage());
}
```

with this example, the `application/plugins` folder, create the `PRoutage.php` plugin like this:

```
class Application_Plugin_PRoutage extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function dispatchLoopStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {         
    ...
    }
}
```

and with the variable `$request` you have access to your data as an array with `$request->getParams()`. 
We can imagine something like this:

```
public function dispatchLoopStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
{         
    $param = $request->getParams();
    $what = "";
    $shape = "";
    if (isset($param['what'])  $what  = $param['what'];
    if (isset($param['shape']) $shape = $param['shape'];

    if ($what == "XXXX" && $shape == "YYYY"){
        $request->setControllerName('other_controler')
                ->setActionName('other_action')
                ->setDispatched(true) ;
    }
}
```

I hope it will help you

Comment: hi, thanks ;) it is a bit of help of course ;) I will think of that solution if nothing else will come up, but I think I should also mention I'm working on a legacy code and I have a similar situation (another form) pointing to a route without any parameters specified and those get "translated" to /key1/value1/key2/value2 : ( I've compared these two forms and routes and they have no difference - I'm really stuck on that, because I can't figure out the possible source of the problem

Comment: Thank's for your return. I update my answer, maybe the js solution is good for you. ;)